# Converting raster image plot graphics into vector info in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vector-graphics, raster

If I have an image (jpg), how can I get the `histogram` of the plot that is shown in the image using `Matlab`? Note here that I don't want the histogram of the image, but just as the list of values of the line the image presents. For example as follows:

0 ---> 4

1 ---> 5

2 ---> 8

**EDIT** 
For example, I got the histogram of an image as shown below. How can I get this histogram as a list of values?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean the image is a raster file (jpg,png,...) and you want to retrieve the data in the plot, or do you have the actual data if the plot?

Comment: @nate. Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have the `.jpg` image. Is it possible to retrieve the data of the histogram?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options you can use:

1. [Graph Digitzer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23317-graph-digitzer)
2. [Manually Digitize Scanned Chart](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27884-manually-digitize-scanned-chart)
3. [Image to data](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1282-image-to-data)
4. [GRABIT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7173-grabit)
5. [digitize2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/928-digitize2-m)